# Making a swiftUI package

Tags: swift, configuration, swiftui, package

I made a simple package for swiftUI. [Here it is](https://github.com/ArnavMotwani/CircularProgressSwiftUI)

Technically, the package I created works. If I take the View struct from the package and put it into a project, it works correctly. My problem is that I have no idea how to configure my project and write the test for it, I can't find any information for swiftUI packages either. I tried copying another package but it didn't work for me.

How can I configure my package for the swiftUI view I created?

Comment: So do you want to write a test, or something else?

Comment: If you web search WWDC Swift Packages you will find a handful of videos from WWDC19 and WWDC20 that explain packages. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/

Comment: @aheze there is a test in every swift package that I don’t know how to write

Comment: @ArnavMotwani check out [9:27](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/?time=567) in the link above